# Exponential in X-Path

Tags: xpath-2.0, exponential, exp

The W3 has released X-Path 3.0 which can handle the followings accordingly.

At this point, my environment is still X-Path 2.0, hence the issue I'm facing.

Kindly help on how do I get this running in X-Path,

```
10 * 10^3;
```

The scenario given as follows,

```
1) Decimals: '3';  
2) Weight: '99';
```

The idea here is to get the final Weight based on the Decimals.
The result here would be **'0.099'**.

In order for me to achieve this, I would need to take

```
(99 div (10 * 10^3));
```

The question,
How can I get **10^3** using X-Path 2.0.
Or are there other ways which stills incorporates X-Path but from a different angle?

Thank you Community.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? XPath is usually hosted by another language -- is XSLT 2.0 the hosting language, or if not, could you, please describe the hosting environment?

Answer (score 1):

**I. Here is an XPath 2.0 expression that produces the result** of multiplying an integer by a positive or negative integer power of 10.

We denote the integer by `$n` and the power by `$decPow`.

Also, I have chosen to iterate `$decPow` in the interval [-3, 3]:

```
 for $n in 999, $decPow in (-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3), 
     $n-length in string-length(string($n)),
     $zeros in string-join(for $i in 1 to abs($decPow)
                                 return '0',
                               '')
  return
    if($decPow ge 0)
      then
            concat($n, $zeros)
          else
            if(abs($decPow) ge $n-length)
              then
                 concat('0.', substring($zeros, $n-length +1), $n)
              else
                concat(
                       substring(string($n), 1, abs(abs($decPow) - $n-length)), 
                       '.', 
                       substring(string($n), abs(abs($decPow) - $n-length) +1)
                       )
```

When this XPath 2.0 expression is evaluated, the expected, correct result is produced:

```
0.0999 0.999 9.99 99.9 999 9990 99900 999000
```

**Below is a validation using an XSLT 2.0 transformation** (it just evaluates the expression and outputs the result):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
    "for $n in 999, $decPow in (-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3), 
         $n-length in string-length(string($n)),
         $zeros in string-join(for $i in 1 to abs($decPow)
                                     return '0',
                                   '')
      return
        if($decPow ge 0)
          then
                concat($n, $zeros)
              else
                if(abs($decPow) ge $n-length)
                  then
                     concat('0.', substring($zeros, $n-length +1), $n)
                  else
                    concat(
                           substring(string($n), 1, abs(abs($decPow) - $n-length)), 
                           '.', 
                           substring(string($n), abs(abs($decPow) - $n-length) +1)
                           ) 
    "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced:

```
0.0999 0.999 9.99 99.9 999 9990 99900 999000
```

---

II. **In case one can use XSLT 2.0, then the FXSL library offers functions for exponentiation (the power can be any double -- not only integer) and logarithmic functions**.

Here is a quick demo:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="f xs"
 >

  <xsl:import href="../f/func-exp.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template name="initial" match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="vPi" as="xs:double" 
         select="3.1415926535897932384626433832795E0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vE" as="xs:double" select="2.71828182845904E0"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="f:log10(100E0)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="f:pow($vPi, $vE)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="f:pow(1024E0, 0.1E0)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="f:log2(1024E0)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="f:ln(f:pow($vE, $vPi))"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="f:pow(f:pow($vE, $vPi), 1 div $vPi)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="f:pow(2 div 3, 99)"/>

    -------------
<xsl:text/>
    <xsl:value-of separator="'&#xA;'" select=
     "for $vN in (-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,
                   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
          return f:pow(10, $vN)
     "
     />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct results are produced**:

```
2.000000001444001
22.459157762347406
1.999999999538168
9.999999955017541
3.1415926541687718
2.718281828960005
3.6894816398697386E-18

    -------------
1.0000000000000008E-10'
'1.000000000000001E-9'
'1.0000000000000008E-8'
'1.0000000000000006E-7'
'0.0000010000000000000004'
'0.000010000000000000004'
'0.00010000000000000005'
'0.0010000000000000002'
'0.010000000000000002'
'0.1'
'1'
'10'
'100'
'1000'
'10000'
'100000'
'1.0E6'
'1.0E7'
'1.0E8'
'1.0E9'
'1.0E10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need powers of ten and not more than 15 digits precision, you can cast it to double:

```
xs:double(concat($weight, "E", -$decimals) )
```

This works, because a double value like `99E-3` is `99 div 1000.0`